# Multi numbering system for lists

Tags: lists

I'm quite new to latex and I've been trying to create a multi level numbering of my list of items, and it turned out to be too 'complex' for me.
I tried a few things already, but with no good outcomes.

I imagined a system like this (dont mind what the text is saying):

[image]

But instead of starting count from "DN 1.1" again, I'm trying to get "DN 1.3", then "DN 1.4" and so on.
(I think) The problem is that I want to have 2numbering "levels" active at the same time.

Again, I'm new so it might be obvious to some (if not all) of y'all how to do this. If someone could just point me in the right direction that would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be good to see the code you're using now, to know whether what we're suggesting is compatible with it.

However, you should be able to set list styles with the `enumitem` package, and make it resume lists within the same section; and then with the help of the `titlesec` package, give the command to reset the numbering at each section.

But I don't even know if you're treating those things as "sections", or as lists within lists, etc.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}

\setlist{label={DN \thesection.\arabic*\ :},ref={\thesection.\arabic*},leftmargin=*,resume}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}

\subsection{First subsection}

\begin{enumerate}
\item First item
\item Second item
\end{enumerate}

\subsection{Next subsection}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Third item in section 1\label{here}
\item Fourth item in section 1
\end{enumerate}

\section{Second section}
\restartlist{enumerate}

\subsection{Another subsection}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Another section's item
\item Yet another item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: output image]

Comment: To be honest I don't even know the difference between treating things as sections or lists withing lists... Will definitely look into that. Your answer helped anyway, so thank you.